# Django south - can't remove null

Tags: django, django-south

I have a Django model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to change the product field to:

```
    ...
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

But when I change it and run the South migration I get:

```
    django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1005, "Can't create table 'mydb.#sql-3f5_208'    (errno: 121)")
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever fix the problem?

Comment: Hey could you solve the problem, I am facing a similar problem when I try removing the blank=True constraint in one of the fields

Answer (score 0):

That error appear because you use InnoDB tables, and you get 121 error because database you have some troubles with your keys.
When I got that error I resolve it by recreating database :)

You also can try to read InnoDB error log files.

P.S. Try to add some data to tables, sometimes it works.

Comment: Surely if I recreate the db South is going to complain about tables not existing. Or do you mean restart the South history with `--initial`?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error while installing easy_thumbnails. It turned out it was a bug in South 0.7.3 which was easily fixed by installing South 0.8.1. I don't know if that's the same problem but given that you're using South it seems like it might be.